# The meaning of a closed differential inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, definition

I'm currently reading [Villani's notes on hypocoercivity](https://cedricvillani.org/sites/dev/files/old_images/2012/07/043.Hypoco.pdf) and on pp87 it states that the differential inequality (14.10):
$$ \frac{d}{dt}(\mathcal E (f) - \mathcal E(f_\infty)) = -\mathcal D(f) \leq -K_\epsilon(\mathcal E(f) - \mathcal E(f_\infty))^{1+\epsilon} $$
cannot in general be 'closed'. What does it mean for a differential inequality to be closed?

Comment: I think the following link will help you a lot: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9199/what-does-closed-form-solution-usually-mean

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I don't think this is what I'm looking for. I'm not interested in solving the equation and finding a closed form solution - I'm only interested in whether the differential inequality implies decay of $\mathcal E(f)$ to $\mathcal E(f_\infty)$.

Comment: Then your question should have been more specific than the current form. @meaninglesspen

Comment: On the contrary I think I've been very specific - I gave a link to the precise equation where Villani used 'closed' and I'm obviously asking for the meaning of 'closed' in the given context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, if we have a inequality of the form as you wrote: $$\frac{d}{dt}(\mathcal E (f) - \mathcal E(f_\infty)) = -\mathcal D(f) \leq -K_\epsilon(\mathcal E(f) - \mathcal E(f_\infty))^{1+\epsilon},$$ with $K_\epsilon$ being a constant depending only on $\epsilon$, this would imply that $\mathcal{E}(f)$ decays to $\mathcal E(f_\infty)$ polynomially fast in time. However, I think Villani's (14.10) stated instead that
$$\frac{d}{dt}(\mathcal E (f) - \mathcal E(f_\infty)) = -\mathcal D(f) \leq -K_\epsilon\left(\mathcal E(f) - \mathcal E(\Pi_1 f)\right)^{1+\epsilon},$$ this inequality is clearly "not closed" (in the sense that no information regarding the decay of $\mathcal{E}(f)$ to $\mathcal E(f_\infty)$ can be inferred from this inequality).

Side remark: I have also read a bit Villani's "*Hypocoercivity*" so maybe we can discuss more on his monograph if you want, also I think my question (with a bounty) [A possible error in Villani's monograph “Hypocoercivity”](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4069062/a-possible-error-in-villanis-monograph-hypocoercivity) might interest you as well.

Comment: Sorry for the overdue acceptance, and thanks for the clarification. It turns out I did misread the inequality as you said. I'm not able to help with your question as well, sorry, I'm not reading the monograph in detail at the moment.